# Проверить просрочено или нет

Tags: классы, pascal, record

Здраствуйте, помогите придумать, как проверить условие:

```
(Текущая_дата-(дата_изготовления + срок_годности)) > 0?
```

> ```
> Текущая_дата:MyDate;
> Дата_изготовления:MyDate;
> Срок_годности:Integer;
> ```

Дата описывается записью состоящей из 3 integer : year, month, day.

**Нельзя** пользоваться функциями для работы с временем!!!

**UPD:**

```
type
  date = record
    y : integer;
    m : integer;
    d : integer;
  end;

var
  izgotovleno, segodnya : date;
  godnost : integer;
begin
  izgotovleno.y := 2017;
  izgotovleno.m := 12;
  izgotovleno.d := 29;

  segodnya.y := 2018;
  segodnya.m := 1;
  segodnya.d := 5;

  godnost := 9;

  writeln( ((segodnya.y*100)+(segodnya.m*10)+segodnya.d) - (((izgotovleno.y*100)+(izgotovleno.m*10)+izgotovleno.d)+godnost)>0 );
end.
```

Comment: Смысл этого задания в том, чтобы Вы чему-то научились, а не в том, что Вы скопируете код, который Вам напишет какой-нибудь доброхот из Интернета.

Comment: И в чем у вас сложности возникли? Вы паскаль-то знаете хоть как-то?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов да я знаю всё, я не знаю как это всё сделать с учётом высокосных дат и всё такое

Comment: То есть вопрос в високосных годах? Почему бы вам не задавать конкретные вопросы?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ну да, я просто спросила у друзей, просто повычитать и всё, ну они сказали что нужно учитывать много факторов, то-есть, высокосный ли год, сколько дней в месяце и то что срок годности может быть больше года.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Нет, в "високосных годах и всём таком". (Укладчица Иванова)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов мне именно логическое решение нужно, набить то на паскале я хоть что могу

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов А vihtor правильную идею говорит?

Comment: @olyakoroleva вы же можете набить на паскале что угодно, вот и проверьте правильно он говорит или нет.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ок

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ну сделала я и не правильно, так как должно выдавать true, потому-что срок годности в новом году ещё не истёк!

Comment: `godnost := 9;` - девять чего? ("В третьем бочонке 24 огурца.")

Comment: @Igor это кол-во дней

Comment: Нельзя умножать месяц на десять и складывать с днями, разве это не очевидно? Без анализа на високосность и количество дней в разных месяцах Вам не обойтись. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4